# Why it does not know the same content?

Tags: svelte, sapper, sapui5

I've build an example app in svelte and sapper with same ui and figure out, the content appears different:

Svelte
[image]

Sapper
[image]

I've checked the css, but it should not be any differences.
The code from https://gitlab.com/oceanstack/ui5-sapper and https://gitlab.com/oceanstack/ui5-svelte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your HTML is not the same.

Svelte:

`<ui5-label id="myLabel" for="myInput" required show-colon="">First name</ui5-label>`

Sapper:

`<ui5-label id="myLabel" for="myInput" show-colon="">First name</ui5-label>`

Notice that Svelte has the `required` attribute and Sapper does not.

If you go into the browser development tools on the Sapper page and add the `required` attribute to the label, you'll notice that all of a sudden, the ellipsis is removed and that your labels will match.

Comment: Now, I've changed it and it should be the same. What do I have to do to get the same UI as in svelte? I am new in sapper world.

Comment: If your code is the same in both, they should be identical. The question you should be asking yourself is if you even need Sapper in the first place.

Comment: I need Sapper because routing. The code is now the same, but it does not show the same ui. Why?

Comment: Could you please download it and try it out and then you will see the difference.

Comment: Keep in mind that Sapper is not the only option for routing. There are other routing options available for Svelte. Unless you have a more specific need from Sapper, you might be better served with something easier like `svelte-spa-router`. I'm guessing that because you don't know how to spot the difference (use your browser's Inspect Element feature on both and you will see the CSS differences) suggests to me that you might not be ready to use Sapper.

Comment: You are absolutely right. By the way, why it does not render properly, it is a bug. You should try it out. Sapper does not render correctly

Comment: You need to look at the HTML in the inspector. You will see that `required` did not pass through to the rendered HTML. That's because you didn't assign a true or false value to it, i.e. `required={true}` By using Sapper, you're adding a layer of difficulty that you may not be ready for. I think you should stick to pure Svelte until you understand what Sapper is.

Comment: The bug happens in the Svelte hydration, opened a bug ticket: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4579

Comment: For the time being, you can heed @Braintapper 's advice by adding  `required={true}`. instead of just `required`

it is in the server rendered HTML, if you try disable JavaScript in your browser, you should see it.
it was removed when the js kicks in and removes it.